# Custom Format div in TinyMCE Merges with previous div

Tags: php, wordpress, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have created a custom format in the editor with

```
array(
    'title' => 'Tab',
    'block' => 'div',
    'classes' => 'tab',
    'wrapper' => true,
    'exact' => true,
),
```

I can then use it by selecting some text and choosing my format to get:

```
<div class="tab">
   <h3>My Content heading 1</h3>
   <p>My first bit of content here...</p>
</div>
```

So far, so good. However when I select the following text and choose my format it extends the existing div rather than inserting a new one so I end up with:

```
<div class="tab">
  <h3>My Content heading 1</h3>
  <p>My first bit of content here...</p>
  <h3>My Content heading 2</h3>
  <p>My second bit of content here...</p>
</div>
```

When what I want is this:

```
<div class="tab">
  <h3>My Content heading 1</h3>
  <p>My first bit of content here...</p>
</div>
<div class="tab">
  <h3>My Content heading 2</h3>
  <p>My second bit of content here...</p>
</div>
```

Setting the "exact" parameter when creating the format doesn't seem to change this behaviour when I would expect it to. Help me, please.

Comment: This might help you - https://gist.github.com/trepmal/1260520.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add these functions to your theme's 'functions.php' for registering new button in TinyMCE.

```
// init scripts
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_tinymce_theme_setup' );

if ( ! function_exists( 'custom_tinymce_theme_setup' ) ) {
    function custom_tinymce_theme_setup(){
        add_action( 'admin_init', 'custom_tinymce_theme_add_editor_styles' );
        add_action( 'init', 'custom_tinymce_buttons' );
    }
}

// add editor custom css
if ( ! function_exists( 'custom_tinymce_theme_add_editor_styles' ) ) {
    function custom_tinymce_theme_add_editor_styles() {
        add_editor_style( 'custom-editor-style.css' );
    }
}

// add editor button filter
if ( ! function_exists( 'custom_tinymce_buttons' ) ) {
    function custom_tinymce_buttons() {
        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) && ! current_user_can( 'edit_pages' ) ) {
            return;
        }
        if ( get_user_option( 'rich_editing' ) !== 'true' ) {
            return;
        }

        add_filter( 'mce_external_plugins', 'custom_tinymce_add_buttons' );
        add_filter( 'mce_buttons', 'custom_tinymce_register_buttons' );
    }
}

// call editor custom js
if ( ! function_exists( 'custom_tinymce_add_buttons' ) ) {
    function custom_tinymce_add_buttons( $plugin_array ) {
        $plugin_array['wrap_tab'] = get_template_directory_uri().'/js/tinymce_buttons.js';
        return $plugin_array;
    }
}

// add button to editor
if ( ! function_exists( 'custom_tinymce_register_buttons' ) ) {
    function custom_tinymce_register_buttons( $buttons ) {
        array_push( $buttons, 'wrap_tab' );
        return $buttons;
    }
}
```

Then create a new JS file named 'tinymce_buttons.js' under your '[theme]/js' directory and add the following code.

```
(function() {
    tinymce.PluginManager.add( 'wrap_tab', function( editor, url ) {
        editor.addButton('wrap_tab', {
            title: 'Insert Tab',
            cmd: 'wrap_tab',
            text: 'Tab',
        });

        editor.addCommand('wrap_tab', function() {
            var selected_text = editor.selection.getContent({
                'format': 'html'
            });
            if ( selected_text.length === 0 ) {
                alert( 'Please select text that needs to be wrapped.' );
                return;
            }
            var return_content = '<div class="tab">' + selected_text + '</div>';
            editor.execCommand('mceReplaceContent', false, return_content);
            return;
        });
    });
})();
```

You can then include the CSS styles - create a new CSS file named 'custom-editor-style.css' under your theme folder with style definitions to your DIV element.

```
#tinymce .tab{ padding:10px; border: 1px #666 solid; }
```

Hope this helps and credits goes to https://madebydenis.com/adding-custom-buttons-in-tinymce-editor-in-wordpress/.